# CMake создание библиотек

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Как сделать чтобы CMake генерировал решение где бы был проект который создавал статическую и динамическую библиотеку? На данный момент у меня происходит генерация двух проектов для создания одной библиотеки, статической и динамической.

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что Visual Studio может из одного проекта сгенерировать 2 разных библиотеки? Вы так в самой студии можете сделать?

Comment: Я видел библиотеку где так было сделано.

Comment: Значит смотрите как сделана та библиотека и делайте так же.

Comment: Если бы я хорошо разбирался в CMake, то я бы так и сделал и не задавал тут вопросы, а если и вы в этом не разбираетесь, то не нужно оставлять бесполезные комментарии.

Comment: Видите ли, я как раз неплохо разбираюсь как в CMake так и в студии, и я ни разу не встречал возможности сделать то, что Вы хотите. В этом банально нет никакого смысла. Я не буду на 100% утверждать, что это невозможно, но скорее всего это именно так.